# Problem with HTML5 input type number dynamic validation with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I have a dynamic input generated with a simple `jQuery(...).apend(...)` that draw this code on my webpage:

```
<input type="number" name="19000003" min="0" max="99999999" required="" step="0.1"
oninput="/^(?:\d{0,8})(?:,\d{0,3})?$/.test(this.value) ? this.value : this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1);">
```

I can validate the first part (maximum size of characters including ','), but it gives me an error when y try to validate decimals.

> he specified value "111." is not a valid number. The value must match
>   to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

When I test the regex code on the Chrome console it works (like these examples)

```
/^(?:\d{0,8})(?:,\d{0,3})?$/.test('1234,12');
/^(?:\d{0,8})(?:,\d{0,3})?$/.test('123,');
```

but doesn't works inside the input. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp does not work because you are trying to match a `,` on the input. However, even if you see a `,` on the browser, internally It is stored as `.` (probably to avoid the sort of problems you are facing now when the browser  uses different locales)

So use `/^\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/` for your regex instead.

Here I leave a demo of the code. I have added an `alert` for every keypress so you can see how It is stored. Try to write `1,1` and see what happens.

```html
<input type="number" name="19000003" min="0" max="99999999" required="" step="0.1"
oninput="alert(this.value); /^\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/.test(this.value) ? this.value : this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1);">
```

Comment: Oh ok I understand. Thanks you very much. I spent a lot of time without considering that point.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Julio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458571/5582809)

note that `step="0.1"` can also break your form validation.

It's better to adhere to your regex validation (for 3 decimals, `step="0.001"`)

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Allowing_decimal_values)

Comment: That's true I'll adapt that part too. Lots of thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to separate function from element

```js
    const myElement = document.getElementById("someInput");
    myElement.oninput = function(ev) {
        /^(?:\d{0,8})(?:,\d{0,3})?$/.test(this.value) ? this.value : this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
    }
```

```html
    <input type="number" id="someInput" name="19000003" min="0" max="99999999" required="" step="0.1" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but doesn't works too and the idea is to have it dynamic without external functions, but thanks

Comment: While that is a good practice, It has nothing to do about what OP asked...